# Schedule blackberry notification

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Blackberry 10.2 Cascades.

Is it possible to schedule a blackberry notification to fire at specific time(like on iOS), even when application is turned off? I successfully fired a notification while the app was in background as well as while in active state. The only alternative that comes to my mind is to schedule an event in the calendar, but I can't really respond to it by launching the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A present unfortunately the answer is no. With the release of 10.2.1 you could do this with a long-running headless application, but that seems like overkill. If you have a strong use case I would suggest you reach out to BlackBerry to request they add timer events to the list of triggers that can invoke short-running headless applications. This seems like a good fit for that paradigm, and BlackBerry have asked for developers to submit ideas for additional triggers.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer :) Thank you very much.

Comment: On the plus side it seems like a logical trigger to add to the short-running headless specification. If you ask it may even make it into 10.2.1.